# Return parents 3 levels deep in one sql

Tags: mysql

See the [demo here:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c9cd/1)
Where its missing: "Sports » Rugby League » Results" and a few other.

The problem is caused from the last IF statement in the WHERE. This was added to ensure that the pages/parents will only go 3 levels deep, when you remove this we end up with "Football » Results » Championship" which doesn't reference the top level.

Everything points back to the top page_id = 1.

```
SELECT
    p1.page_id,
    IF( p1.parent_page_id >1,
    (    SELECT
        IF( p2.parent_page_id >1,
        (    SELECT
            CONCAT( pd3.page_description_name,
            ' » ',
            pd2.page_description_name,
            ' » ',
            pd1.page_description_name )  
        FROM
            pages p3  
        LEFT JOIN
            page_descriptions pd3 
                ON pd3.page_id = p3.page_id  
                AND pd3.language_id = '1'  
        WHERE
            p3.page_id = p2.parent_page_id  LIMIT 1 ) ,
        CONCAT( pd2.page_description_name,
        ' » ',
        pd1.page_description_name ) )  
    FROM
        pages p2  
    LEFT JOIN
        page_descriptions pd2 
            ON pd2.page_id = p2.page_id  
            AND pd2.language_id = '1'  
    WHERE
        p2.page_id = p1.parent_page_id  LIMIT 1  ), pd1.page_description_name  ) AS path  
FROM
    pages p1  
LEFT JOIN
    page_descriptions pd1 
        ON pd1.page_id = p1.page_id  
        AND pd1.language_id = '1'  
WHERE
    IF( p1.parent_page_id >1, (    SELECT
        IF( p3.parent_page_id  IN ( 1,
        0 ) ,
        1,
        0 )  
    FROM
        pages p3  
    WHERE
        p3.page_id = p1.parent_page_id  LIMIT 1 ) , 1  )  
    AND p1.page_id !=1  
ORDER BY
    path
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your desired result.

Comment: Return a list of pages with (id + full path), which is restricted to 3 levels from Home. So the 4level would always be equal 1

Comment: Is this a query your system will be running often?  If so, it is going to be horribly inefficient.  You also have not shared any information on your table schema and sample data.  This could help identify if you have areas for improvement there. Representing tree structure in relational databases can always be a bit of a challenge, but it is unclear to me whether you are using any of these techniques (like nested sets or adjacency lists).  Here is a good article on how to utilize these and make you queries more efficient - http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @MikeBrant no this is just an admin function, and the results get saved into another column for quick reference. Thanks for the ink though I will add it to the reading list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a massive join, and as Mike Brant points out in the comments you may be better off looking into another structure if it's a query that is run often, but as far as I understand the requirements, this should work for your current data set;

```
SELECT a.page_id,CONCAT_WS(' » ',c.page_description_name,
                                 b.page_description_name,
                                 a.page_description_name) path
FROM page_descriptions a
LEFT JOIN pages a1 
  ON a.page_id = a1.page_id AND a1.parent_page_id <>1
LEFT JOIN page_descriptions b
  ON b.page_id = a1.parent_page_id
LEFT JOIN pages b1 
  ON b.page_id = b1.page_id AND b1.parent_page_id <>1
LEFT JOIN page_descriptions c
  ON c.page_id = b1.parent_page_id
LEFT JOIN pages c1 
  ON c.page_id = c1.page_id  AND c1.parent_page_id <>1
WHERE (c1.parent_page_id IS NULL OR c1.parent_page_id=0)
  AND a.page_description_id <> 1
```

[An SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a21f/3).

Comment: Thanks for this although this notquite correct. The parent_page_id is the parent page_id not the page_description_id because a many can have many descriptions but only one parent page.

Comment: @JohnMagnolia Updated the query to use page_id instead.

Comment: Thanks, I need to remember CONCAT_WS makes the code easier to read without IF statements

Comment: Out of interest what does the `<>` do? I read it as greater than OR less than 1, is this correct?

Comment: @JohnMagnolia It's just the same as `!=`, not equals.